# multiple not() exceptions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
$('#main a:not([href*="#"])')...
```

Whats the right way (or is it even possible) ti add another not exception for those links?

e.g. right now I'm selecting all links inside of #main that do NOT contain a #hash in its uri.
However I need to make a second exception. Whenever a link contains `[href*="?forum="]`

Any idea how I can add both not-exceptions to this selector?

thank you.

Comment: You could simply add another `:not()`. But as the answers suggest, using the `.not()` function is likely more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so do the second `not` on the outside:

```
$('#main a:not([href*="#"])').not('[href*="?forum="]')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply chain the nots: `$('#id').not(':checkbox').not('something');`

Answer (score 0):

Use the functional version `.not()` and chain the calls:

```
$('#main a').not('sela').not('selb')
```

which should only return those elements that match *neither* sub-selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it without chaining nots, simply:

```
$('#main a:not([href*="#"]):not([href*="?forum="])')
```

See the fiddle for an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tHCss/